# How to deal with printing in a mixed-mode project?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, c++-cli

I have a mixed-mode project C#(WPF) -> C++/Cli -> unmanaged C++.

The graphics is dealt with in c++. Some things are drawn and then transferred to c# thru a c++/cli interface object. In c# this interface is put on a xaml form and shown.

Now I need to send this picture to a printpreview and then to a printer.

How can it possibly be done?

I thought about serializing, but couldn't find anything about serializing c++/cli interfaces.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**
Ok, so I have to explain further on.

In my c# project I have a c++/cli object, through which I can communicate to my graphics in c++, and this object has many methods, like f.ex:

```
object.DrawLine
object.DrawSmthElse
object.UpdateImage
```

etc. etc.

So, when in WPF I show a xaml form, the filling of this form is happening through this object, like I call all these methods to draw all the things I need.

Now the question is: I need to send to printer exactly this graphics part (which is done in c++). In what form should I do it? How can I pass this object to a DocumentViewer in c# for example?

I hope that would be enough to put the question off hold.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the raw bytes of the bitmap to/from managed code and unmanaged code.

On the managed side, you can create a bitmap object [with a Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx).  You can also save an existing bitmap [out to a stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx).  You can use a MemoryStream to easily read and write bytes to/from managed and unmanaged code within your C++/CLI objects.

--

If the image is already on the Managed side (i couldn't tell if it is or not), then you can use the PrintPreviewDialog and PrintDialog ([example](http://www.morgadinho.org/2007/02/27/c-printing-an-image-file/))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Probably I don't understand smth to the end, but I don't have a bitmap but a complicated interface object with some public methods thru which I can communicate from c# to the unmanaged code. In this case to put it to a MemoryStream I will have to deal with serialization again? Or am I wrong?